# measure memory consumption of a make run

Tags: memory, makefile

I would like to measure how much memory what the memory consumption over the course of a build process in Linux (`make`) of a large software project is. Ideally, the consumption would be split up per action (i.e., compilation, linking), but a graph over time might suffice at first.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

`%M` offers you the memory used in KB

If you add, for example:

```
export TIME=\n  real\t%es\n  user\t%Us\n  sys\t%Ss\n  mem\t%MKB
```

After a certain instruction, you will have time and memory consumed.